# SNMP - V3 - i Missing type/value for variable

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

im trying to send a snmptrap but im getting an error "i: Missing type/value for variable"

i already saw some scripts as example and i cannot found the problem. everything seems correct

my command:

```
eval snmptrap -v 3 -u XXX -l authPriv -a SHA -A XXXPASS -x AES-128 -X XXXPASS2 testserver:20462 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.11150.106.1.1.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.11150.1.3.23 i 33
```

Error: "i: Missing type/value for variable"

Thank you in advance.

Best Regard,
Paulo Serra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing the Engine Id. Simple issue.

Thank you